# How could I split this string in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm learning Python (3). I would like to split each of these lines into four separate pieces.

```
[Test Branch]             bobjones       0         6/13/2008 4:24 PM
[Todd's Workspace]        tfatcher       0         6/16/2008 9:20 AM
[Henry]                   hmckinkley     1         6/17/2008 10:12 AM
[Henry]                   hmckinkley     0         6/17/2008 10:15 AM
```

I could call line.split() on each one, but then I'd put the date back together. And I guess the spaces in the first [ ] section rules that out also. I suppose I could slice it, but I'm not 100% sure this data is as fixed width as it seems. A regex is probably best, eh? Any pointers on that?

Update:
I thought @Selcuk's solution this was going to work great:

```
branch,user,version,timestamp = [commitheaderline.split("]", 1)[0] + "]"] + commitheaderline.split("]", 1)[1].split(None, 2)
```

But then I encountered some data where the username was too long (example below), so the rest of the data ended up on a new line. So I'm working on that now. I'm thinking I test the line somehow before running the split(), and if it doesn't look like a "proper" line I'll join it with the next one.

```
[Test Branch]             bobjones       0         6/13/2008 4:24 PM
[Todd's Workspace]        tfatcher       0         6/16/2008 9:20 AM
[cole]                    bob.darknsdale
                                         0        7/27/2012 12:49 PM
```

Comment: Anything you tried on your own?

Comment: Briefly: `line.split(None, 4)`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 This will also split `"[Test"` and `"Branch]"`

Comment: @Selcuk - Good point. Reopened.

Comment: I'd use re.split(" {2,}", str)

Comment: A regex like this should work here. `^(\[.*\])\s*(.*)\s*(\d+)\s*(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}\s\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} [AP]M)$`

Comment: @sakurashinken - What if one of the fields has a bit more content and there's only one space between it and the next column's field?

Comment: Cases like this are the reason the CSV format came about.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 it's the output from an SCM (Surround), it's meant to be human readable, that's why it's not CSV, but I need to parse it and load into Git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
[line.split("]", 1)[0] + "]"] + line.split("]", 1)[1].split(None, 2)
```

which will result in

```
['[Test Branch]', 'bobjones', '0', '6/13/2008 4:24 PM']
```

Comment: I get an index out of range error
            `commitdetails = [part.split("]", 1)[0] + "]"] + part.split("]", 1)[1].split(None, 2)`.  Probably because I have some other data lines that get run through this also (I'm ignoring them for the moment)

Comment: Yes, it works when I strip out the extraneous lines.

Comment: Arg I found a problem, I encountered some data I didn't expect. I'll update my question.

Comment: You should run some pre-processing to eliminate things like extras spaces in the first field, etc. Your data seems to need a cleanup before it can be parsed properly.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
import re
sep = re.split(" {2,}", str)
```

This will work if the strings are separated by more than one whitespace. If they are tab delineated try

```
import re
sep = re.split("\t+", str)
```

Comment: This will fail when there's only one space between as @TigerhawkT3 commented and when there are multiple spaces in a column value.

Comment: Maybe the OP should elaborate on the specifics he/she is working with. It works for the examples given.

Comment: could replace the space with `\s`, `re.split("\s{2,}", str)`, then it will handle both space/tab

Comment: I thought this would work great, but if "Todd's  Workspace" has two spaces in it, it ends up splitting that up.

Comment: What kind of delineation can you rely on?  Are there multiple spaces in the dates and bracketed fields? if a field is too long, what happens? we need some examples of corner cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [4]: import re

In [5]: print text

[Test Branch]             bobjones       0         6/13/2008 4:24 PM
[Todd's Workspace]        tfatcher       0         6/16/2008 9:20 AM
[Henry]                   hmckinkley     1         6/17/2008 10:12 AM
[Henry]                   hmckinkley     0         6/17/2008 10:15 AM


In [6]: pattern = re.compile(r'(\[.*?\])\s+(\w+)\s+(\d+)\s+(.*?$)', re.M)


In [7]: for match in pattern.finditer(text):
   ...:     #do whatever you want here. cols are grouped
   ...:     print "first col: %s - 4th col: %s" %(match.group(1), match.group(4))
   ...:
   ...:
first col: [Test Branch] - 4th col: 6/13/2008 4:24 PM
first col: [Todd's Workspace] - 4th col: 6/16/2008 9:20 AM
first col: [Henry] - 4th col: 6/17/2008 10:12 AM
first col: [Henry] - 4th col: 6/17/2008 10:15 AM
```

This will work with any size of spaces or tabs.